# How to tell whether a point is more to the right of a segment?

Tags: geometry

[image]

How can I tell what is the first segment to the right of $AB$? So we start walking from $A$, reach $B$ and then I need to go most right - to $C$. But how do I find this mathematically? Bear in mind that there could be more segments from $B$ in any direction. (some of them or all of them could be to the left of $B$ - in my image $C$ and $D$ are to the right)

We do have all coordinates of vertices - $x$ and $y$!

I am thinking to

- find if $C$ and $D$ are to the right or left of line going trough $AB$,
- if both are to the right, draw a perpendicular from $C$ to $AB$ and a perpendicular from $D$ to $AB$ and the shortest distance from $A$ to the perpendiculars is the winner?

Comment: To see that the projections are insufficient consider a line orthogonal to $AB$ through $A$ then extend the line $BD$ until it intersects this orthogonal line at $D'$ Then replace $BD$ with $BD'$ . The projection would be $A$ itself but it not the result you want.

Answer (score 1):

Define the angle $\theta$ to a point $X$ from the point $B$ relative to the segment $AB$ as follows. Extend the segment $AB$ beyond $B$ to a point $O$. Then $\theta=\pm \angle OBX\in [-180^\circ,180^\circ]$, where we choose $\theta$ to be positive if $X$ is on the same side of the line through $ABO$ as $C$ and $D$, and negative if it's on the other side. Then the segment to the rightmost of $B$ is the one for which $\theta$ is the largest and positive (and similarly the leftmost has $\theta$ the largest and negative. The only ambiguity is for points colinear to $AB$ on the same side of $B$ as $A$. In this case you can either say the are neither to the left nor to the right, or you could say they are simultaneously the most to the left and the most to the right.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Wont it be easier to look at the angles of ABC and ABD now that you are mentioning angles? I can draw triangles and find the angles from the triangles.

Comment: You could form an equivalent formulation without using $O$, you are right, but thinking of walking from $A$ to $B$, you'd be facing the direction of $O$, so this approach seemed more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider sign of Cross Product of vectors BA X BX from position of observer at B.

Using Right Hand Rule.

If positive, X is to the left.

Sign of BA X BO ... if negative then O is to the right of BA.

If zero then straight ahead.